# NiFi use relative path for get and put file processor

Tags: apache-nifi

New to NiFi, struggling with some basics and would be grateful for any assistance...

I need to get files from a remote server and store them on a NiFi server.  Using GetSFTP and PutFile this works ok.  But I wish to keep the relative paths.

ie. on remote server /data/hosts/host01/.... would be copied into /imports/host01/... on NiFi

I have this working by using `/imports/$path:substring(11)}` as the *Directory* value in PutFile.  I have tried using a parameter and a variable to store the *Remote Path* value and tried using the `:length(var1)` function of the Parameter and/or Variable within the the above substring function but nothing seems to work other than hard coding the substring length.

Is their an easier way to keep relative paths with get and put processors??

Answer (score 0):

`GetFile` and `PutFile` require absolute paths for the directories. If you know the relationship between the root directory and the destinations, you can construct the full path using Expression Language.